# Django: How to renew SimpleJWT access token when token are stored in HttpOnly cookies?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt, cookie-httponly

I have stored the **SimpleJWT** `access` and `refresh` tokens in `HttpOnly` cookies. Now, how do I reproduce an `access` token from the `refresh` token once it expires?

In `React` I used `setTimeout()` to request for new `access` token and it worked just fine. Now that I'm storing these as `HttpOnly` cookies, how do I check whether the `access` is valid or not and if not, create and send a new `access` token as `HttpOnly` cookie?

I have this middleware where I add the tokens from cookie to Authorization middleware, is it possible to renew to token in any such middleware:

```
class AuthorizationHeaderMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response=None):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        view_name = '.'.join((view_func.__module__, view_func.__name__))
        #print(view_name)
        if view_name in EXCLUDE_FROM_MIDDLEWARE:
            return None
    
    def __call__(self, request):
        access_token = request.COOKIES.get('access')
        if access_token:
            request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = f'Bearer {access_token}'
        return self.get_response(request)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you get and refresh the access token on the backend. Let me know if this doesn't fit your use case.

You can store the expiration time on the cookies once you generate access tokens. On your `__call__` method, check if it's past the expiration time. If so, generate a new token and set that on the cookies along with the new expiration time.

Comment: Yeah I understood your solution. Now, how do I check for the time to expire inside `__call__` and also will it keep running in the background in a loop? Can you please show some code.